# Sessions laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, session

```
class ControlController extends Controller
{
    public function anyadirCarrito($id, $quan) {
        $productoCarrito = (object)array(
            'id' =>$id,
            'cantidad' => $quan,
        );
        \Session::push('cart', $productoCarrito);
        return \Session::get('cart');
    }
}
```

Estoy intentando que cada vez que llame a esta función se almacenen los datos pasados sin sobrescribir los que ya hay, pero cada vez que lo llamo me sobrescribe el array que le paso, que podría hacer para que no sobrescriba los datos cada vez que llamo a la función? Y en caso que quiera pasarle un id y borrar el array asociado pero no los demás que podría hacer?

Comment: Exactamente que versión de Laravel estás usando?

Comment: uso laravel 5.6

Comment: En la documentación dice que para hacerle push a un array es así $request->session()->push('user.teams', 'developers');